# Appium python : multiple click

Tags: python, appium, python-appium

I got a quesition for you,

On my application, i would like to click multiple time (10) on a button.
But the application doesn't accept the tap option, so the following code doesnt work :

```
         multi_click = TouchAction(self.driver)
         multi_click.tap(self.driver.find_element_by_id('logo'),0,0,8)
```

And the click action are too slow to be compted as multiple click if i set a "while" :

```
     while i < 10: 
         self.driver.find_element_by_id('logo').click()
         i+= 1
         print (i)
```

Have you any idea ?

Regards

Comment: Is the code you're trying to run also commented out? If not, why is the code in your question commented out?

Comment: No it's not commented, just a bad copy and paste

Comment: It's done. Have you any idea about my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use ADB for doing such multiclick?

This is pseudo code... Not sure 100% if will work and can't test it right now...

```
def sendClickByAdb(self, logo):
   x = logo.location['x']
   y = logo.location['y']
   procId = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
   while i < 10:
      procId.communicate('input tap '+str(x)+' '+str(y))
      i+=1
      print(i)
```

And the only thing you need to know is to call that method:

```
self.sendClickByAdb(self.driver.find_element_by_id('logo'))
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks you for your reply
But the problem is the same,the delay between each click is up to 1-2 sec with your method. 
So the app doesnt see it as double/triple/... click

Comment: Can you try saving your X and Y coordinates, go to cmd, and type "adb shell input tap x y" and do it fast enough to see if it works?
I guess it won't work, but then you will have to try my python method with Threading for each tap

Comment: And btw... Another thing... can you try this? 
procId.communicate('input tap x y\ninput tap x y\ninput tap x y\ninput tap x y\ninput tap x y\ninput tap x y.....') without using any loop, just 10 times 'input tap x y'

Comment: "adb shell input tap x y"

Comment: "adb shell input tap x y"
This command fast enough works well, so i presume appium is just to slow ...
However i have found another solution which works fine (but not really pretty) :

import shlex
toto = 'adb shell input tap 100 100 && input tap 100 100 && input tap 100 100 && input tap 100 100 && input tap 100 100 && input tap 100 100 && input tap 100 100 && input tap 100 100 && input tap 100 100 && input tap 100 100'
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(toto),stdin = subprocess.PIPE)

(sorry for the double post)

Answer (score 0):

Does a click on this element generate a navigation to another screen ?

If not, did you try a search the element only one time (outside your loop) ?

It will be probably faster.

```
logo = self.driver.find_element_by_id('logo')
while i < 10: 
    logo.click()
    i+= 1
    print (i)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply
However the delay between each click is up to 1-2 sec with your method. Which is quite the same as a element.click on the loop ...